# Merge numbered files with variable names

Tags: bash, merge, cat

I have a number of numbered files, e.g.:
`alpha_01.txt` `alpha_02.txt` `beta_01.txt` `beta_02.txt`
I want to execute a single line bash that will output correctly merged files based on their *variable* name (e.g. alpha, beta, ...), that is, `alpha.txt` `beta.txt`.

I can do so for a single file:

```sh
cat alpha_*.txt(n) >>alpha.txt 2>/dev/null
```

But I don‘t know the name before `_*.txt`.
Can I use a wildcard here? Or what would be the best solution?

Comment: It's not clear what `$name` contains. `cat "$name"_*.txt >"$name".txt` would do what you want if `name` is `alpha`

Comment: Discarding error messages seems dubious here; it would be quite unusual for this operation to fail anyway.

Comment: `for name in alpha beta; do cat "$name"_*.txt >"$name".txt; done`?

Comment: What if I have many variable names? i.e. cannot list them all?

Comment: It's not clear what these other variables are; please [edit] to clarify what you are actually trying to accomplish. Bash can obviously combine multiple variables in a string easily, like `echo "$var1$var2"` so that is not a problem as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate all the `alpha_xxx.txt` files then you cannot have `beta_xxx.txt` in the arguments of `cat`.

As @tripleee said, the easiest way would be to use a `for` loop where you list all the prefixes:

```sh
for name in alpha beta
do
    cat "$name"_*.txt > "$name".txt
done
```

---

Now, if you don't know the prefixes in advance then you can always workout something with `awk`:

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {
        for (i = 1; i <= ARGC; i++) {
            filename = ARGV[i]

            if (filename !~ /^(.*\/)?[^\/]+_[0-9]+\.[^\/.]+$/)
                continue

            match(filename, /^(.*\/)?[^\/]+_/)
            prefix = substr(filename, RSTART, RLENGTH-1)

            match(filename, /\.[^.\/]+$/)
            suffix = substr(filename, RSTART, RLENGTH)

            outfile[filename] = prefix suffix
        }
    }
    FILENAME in outfile { print $0 > outfile[FILENAME] }
' ./*.txt
```